# A subadditive function on a countable join-semilattice

Tags: measure-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

A partial ordered set $(P,\preceq)$ (i.e. a set $P$ endowed with a operation $\preceq$ which is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive) is said to be a *join-semilattice* whenever for all $x,y \in P$ there exists their least upper bound $x \vee y \in P$.

Then, given a join-semilattice $(P,\preceq)$, we fix a subadditive function $f\colon P\to \mathbf{R}$, meaning that 
$$
\forall x,y \in P,\,\,f(x\vee y)\le f(x)+f(y),
$$
*and such that $f(x)<f(y)$ for some $x\preceq y$.* [<- Thank you Ramiro]

**Question:** Is it possible that $P$ is an infinite countable set and for all $x \in P$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in P$ for which $x=\bigvee a_i$ and $f(a_1)<\varepsilon,\ldots,f(a_k)<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Something is strange in your question. As stated, it has a trivial answer:

YES, just take $P=\mathbb{N}$,  $\preceq$ order be the usual $\leqslant$ order, $x \vee y  = \max(x,y)$  and $f=0$.

Comment: Oh you're right :) I edited the question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  For instance, let $P$ be the set of finite unions of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with rational endpoints, ordered by inclusion, and let $f:P\to\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measure.  Since any interval with rational endpoints can be partitioned into finitely many arbitrarily small intervals with rational endpoints, this satisfies your condition.